# Redmine plugin creation - Could not find generator 'redmine_plugin'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine-plugins

I run Redmine 3.4 with Rails (5.2.0) and Docker 18.03.1-ce on Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial (which is new for me), following this GitHub repository: https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-redmine

I create my Rails app in the same folder where the docker-compose.yml has been created, and cd to it.

Then I have the exact same problem than described in this Redmine post (http://www.redmine.org/boards/3/topics/48309?r=48507#message-48507): when I try the command rails generate redmine_plugin Plug_test, this two error messages appear:

- Running via Spring preloader in process 32109
- Could not find generator 'redmine_plugin'

So I try the commands that Keith suggested, and running the generate command again, the Spring error message disappear, but the generate command still doesn't work (Could not find generator 'redmine_plugin').

Any idea what to do? I don't know if I'm going in the right direction.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Ok so for people that would find this post, the solution was simple. 
gem install and bundle all the correct versions in your Gemfile, rails s your app, check your environment (rails r "puts Rails.env"), change it to prod (export RAILS_ENV="production"), and then you can "rails generate redmine_plugin <plug_name>"

Answer (score 0):

well simple problem, you're running command from outside of your redmine app directory, you need to go into your redmine app directory, after that you can run `rails generate redmine_plugin Plugin_test` from there

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but being in my rails app and doing the command it tells me:
$ rails generate redmine_plugin Plugin_test

Running via Spring preloader in process 11306
Could not find generator 'redmine_plugin'. Maybe you meant 'test_unit:plugin', 'resource_route' or 'channel'
Run `rails generate --help` for more options.

So if I'm in the rails app, why it stills doesn't work?

Comment: well i never created redmine plugin, but did you setup the redmine in your local machine and able to run it?

Comment: I use docker to have a Redmine image (i don't know if what i say is understanble), but i tried to run Redmine and it works locally.
Somebody told me that maybe the basic configuration of docker unables to run correctly some redmine commands such as the redmine_plugin generator. but as i'm totally new to docker and redmine, it will be difficult for me to set it correctly. i will try to install a virtual machine to run redmine, hopping the commands needed respond.
Thank you anyway Ravi

Answer (score 0):

As Ravi mentioned above, you need to go into your redmine app directory instead of your rails app directory.

Or, maybe you can exec plugin generate command via docker run command.

```
# e.g. In case plugin name is “myplugin"
docker run --name=redmine -it --rm \
  --volume=/srv/docker/redmine/redmine:/home/redmine/data \
  sameersbn/redmine:3.4.4-2 \
  app:rails generate redmine_plugin myplugin
```

If this works fine, plugin directory named “myplugin” will be generated under /srv/docker/redmine/redmine/plugins/ directory.

Personally, I think, you had batter not use docker to create and development Redmine’s plugin, especially if you are not familiar with Redmine and Docker so much.

I hope this would be any help.

Comment: Thanks Akiko, yes I will let Docker aside for the moment (even if it's a useful tool), and stay on the "normal way".

Comment: Maybe you can also run rails generate redmine_plugin command in a Redmine’s container, with using docker exec command.
In case using docker, it is easy to use docker-compose.yml included in a same repository.